# Trace externally loaded XML data in Flash

Tags: xml, flash, flash-cs4, flashvars

How do I trace all of the data from an XML file that was loaded into a flash file?  I am trying to debug, and part of my flash file gets updated from the XML file, but the other half acts like it isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External XML files are loaded with the URLLoader:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("exteranl.xml"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

function onComplete(event:Event):void
{
    externalXMLdata = new XML(event.target.data);
    trace(externalXMLdata.toXMLString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, you don't need to convert the XML to a string to trace it, that's just an extra step.